# Count 2 or more columns using Pivot table

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

How do I get the pivot table showing the total number of colours available in all the shops. Something like:

> Black - total count
> White - Total Count
> Blue - Total Count

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should have a table like this:
[image]

Insert -> Pivot Table
Check "Add this data to the Data Model" -> OK
[image]

Make your Pivot Table Fields look like this:
[image]

Click on "Count of shop" -> "Value Field Settings..."
Select "Distinct Count" -> OK
[image]

Resulting pivot table:
[image]

The option "Add this data to the Data Model" did the trick. Only with this option you can  have "Distinct Count".

Comment: @HarshadAmichandVegda - thank you for kind words. However, this is all I can do. If you need explanations in email, I will suggest copy-pasting the link to this webpage. As a side note, showing your personal email in the internet is not a wise idea, because bad guys can copy the email and send you spam. I must flag your comment for removal.